# VSTest (not MSTest) WaitHandler.WaitAll STA Thread error

Tags: multithreading, vstest

I am trying it in VS2017. I am writing a test using VSTest framework. Method, for which I am writing this test uses multi threads. While executing test I get STA error. I looked internet and found many suggestions to fix it in runsettings. I already have existing runsettings, I tried to add below entries, nothing seems worked, and still STA error while running the test

For below setting, no Invalid Setting error but STA thread issue remains

```
<RunSettings>      
<!-- ... -->
<TestSettings>
    <Execution>
        <!-- ... -->
    <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
</Execution>
</TestSettings>
```

Invalid settings 'RunConfiguration' for below changes

```
<RunSettings>
<RunConfiguration>
<!-- -->
<ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
</RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

As per this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/configure.md 
 I am changing as below:

```
<RunSettings>
<RunConfiguration>
<!-- -->
<ExecutionThreadApartmentState>MTA</ExecutionThreadApartmentState>
</RunConfiguration>
</RunSettings>
```

But I am still getting error for Invalid settings 'RunConfiguration'.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

As per above link `ExecutionThreadApartmentState` in runsettings supported from VS 2017 update 5. For earlier versions you can set in file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.executionengine.exe.config. Refer: https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/configure.md#execution-thread-apartment-state